# Models and Apps in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-apps

I am creating a Django Project . It has n number of Apps in it . Also it has different models . A model will have to be defined in an App . But the apps are interrelated . So a model defined in one app can also be used in another app . So how to decide where to put a particular app ?

Comment: How do you decide where to put any other code? Now apply the same reasoning to your models. It's convenient (but not required!) to put them in `<app_name>.models` so the `app_label` is automatically detected, other than that, do what makes sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that we are developing a storehouse about electronics. I would made a Django web site with those apps: clients, suppliers, computers, motherboard,  speakers, phones

Of course all of them are connected. I would set the connection on the model of the main one, for example computers and motherboard, I would put it in motherboard.

**Django lets to import apps in other apps.**